# verbs and commas surrounding "as well as"

Tags: grammar, commas

is "provides" correct? And what about commas before or after "as well as" in this sentence:

- *Narrated in the third person omniscient, the narrator depicts a panoramic view of the natural landscape as well as provides an objective view of the main character’s thoughts*.

Comment: Sounds like regular literary review type language to me. In such language, as it is given to run-on sentences, commas are used more sparingly than in regular English. They have to be due to the length of the sentences.

Comment: In other words, you might think it needs a comma on "landscape[,] as well as provides" but that would pair the verb with "Narrated in the third person omniscient" rather than "the narrator depicts a panoramic view" and make it more clunky.

Comment: Here's my improvement of the sentence. "In the third person omniscient, the narrator depicts both a panoramic view of the natural landscape and provides an objective view of the main character's thoughts." Or, howzzabout:  "The narrator, in the third person omniscient, depicts both . . . and provides . . .." Ka-ching! A savings of two words!

Comment: This question is about another aspect of "as well as", but it indicates a comma before but not after (this makes sense, as "as well as" functions as a conjunction rather than as an optional part of the sentence). https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/456637/meaning-and-usage-of-as-well-as

Comment: See also chappo's answer at [verbs after 'as well as' – is this Merriam-Webster example wrong?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/464442/verbs-after-as-well-as-is-this-merriam-webster-example-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

No, *provides* is not correct.

A comma before *as well as* would be useful but not mandatory.

Narrated in the third person omniscient, the narrator depicts a panoramic view of the natural landscape as well as *providing* an objective view of the main character’s thoughts.

FYI, *Narrated (anything), the narrator (anything)* might be grammatically defensible but it's stylistically anathema.

Comment: Robbie Goodwin, would you please provide any recommendations to improve the sentence, given that you described it as "stylistically anathema".

Comment: Ali, you do need to do your own homework. Please look again at *Narrated (anything), the narrator (anything)* and consider among those five words, which might be causing the problem… particularly since the problem was in no way affected by anything I changed

Comment: can I use "Irving" instead of "the narrator"?

Comment: Ali, that would help and still you'd need to change a lot more…

Try parsing the whole passage and see how many subjects you thnk there are, please?

Comment: No matter whether you say “the narrator” or “Irving”, it’s still a dangling modifier. Irving is not narrated in any person—the _story_ is.

Answer (score -1):

Parse it this way:
"(Narrated in the third person omniscient,)
(the narrator **depicts**)
(a panoramic view of the natural landscape)
(as well as **provides**)
(an objective view of the main character’s thoughts.)".

HTH.