# Verbs after 'as well as'—is this Merriam-Webster example wrong?

Tags: style-manuals

Before branding this question a duplicate, please note that I have already noticed some questions here pertaining to the use of 'as well as'. I have also noticed that none of the answers to them are helpful to clear out my confusion.

I have come across this sentence in Michael Swan's Practical English Usage: "When we put a verb after *as well as*, we most often use the *-ing* form".

> **verbs after *as well as***
>
> When we put a verb after *as well as*, we most often use the *-ing* form
>
> *Smoking is dangerous, as well as making you smell bad* [NOT ...<del>as well as it makes you smell bad</del>)
>   As well as breaking his leg, he hurt his arm. (NOT ...<del>as well as he broke his leg…</del>)
>   After an infinitive in the main clause, an infinitive without *to* is possible.
>   *I have to feed the animals, **as well as** look after the children.*
>   Note the difference between:
>
> > She sings as well as playing the piano.
> >     (= She not only plays, but also sings.)
> >     She sings as well as she plays the piano.
> >     (=Her singing is as good as her playing.)

Also, [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/as+well+as) says, "You can use as well as in a similar way to link clauses. However, the second clause must be a clause beginning with an -ing form". See their example sentence and warning:
[image]

But this example sentence form the [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20well%20as) puts me in confusion:
[image]

Question: What is the correct usage when we have to use a verb after *as well as*?

**EDIT**

#### Afterthought:

After reading the answers, my confusion has been worsened. Is the M-W dictionary's example sentence really wrong? I've come across the following sentences in another grammar book.

> Justice, *as well as* mercy, **allows** it.
>
> Sanskrit, *as well as* Arabic, **was** taught there.
>
> The book says that *as well as* is parenthetical and that is why the
>   verbs are singular here.

In other words, it's not a conjunction copulative or additive in function; it's simply appositive.

See what **Fowler** says in his **A Dictionary of Modern English Usage**:

> "It is time for someone to come to the rescue of the phrase *as well
>   as*, which is being cruelly treated. Grammatically, the point is that
>   *as well as* is a *conjunction* and not a *preposition*. Or, to put it in a less abstract way, its strict meaning is not *besides*, but *and
>   not only.*
>
> - *Its authoritative reports would help to build  up  an  informed  public opinion as well as guiding the Government.*
>
>   Read   '***guide***',  it   depends  on *would*; or else substitute
>     *besides*.
> - *His death  leaves  a gap  as  well as creating a by-election in Ross and Cromarty.*
>
>   Read ***creates***; it is parallel to *leaves*; or else substitute 
>     *besides*.

It seems to me as if Fowler asks us not to use an -ing form of verbs after *as well as*, for *as well as* is never a preposition. Also, if we want to use the -ing form, we have to use the preposition *besides*.

My doubt again, especially after reading the appositive use of *as well as* is : Although we may agree with Fowler's views, ***can't we use an -ing verb form (a gerund) after a conjunction?***

Comment: There are two meanings to 'as well as'. _She dances as well as she sings_ is a comparison of ability. _As well as dancing, she sings_ is an addition of ability.

Comment: @NigelJ, Yes, that's clear from the examples of PEU. Such comparisons can be made using other adverbs as: "*She dances as beautifully as she sings*." Could you comment on other two sentences of the Free Dictionary and MW Dictionary?

Comment: Good question +1. It does seem contradictory. I wonder if the free dictionary would accept 'we manage the budget as well as order the equipment', the equivalent of the Meriam Webster example. For no good reason that I can think of, the latter sentence sounds a bit better in my ears than 'she manages the budget as well as orders the equipment'.

Comment: In technical editing—where brevity and clarity are paramount—"as well as" is often changed to "and" (where appropriate) or "in addition to" to avoid the ambiguity noted by @NigelJ. It's more succinct, for example, to simply say "Smoking is dangerous and makes you smell bad." and "We offer electronic toys and rent out video games."

Comment: @SConroy, Sorry, it's my mistake and I'm going to edit it. I meant *'None of them are helpful' in my case. Thanks!

Comment: @Chemomechanics “and also” works too.

Comment: The more I think about this the more I get confused. Here are a couple of other examples to consider. 1. "She has to vacuum the floor as well as mop it." 2."I must go to the doctor's, as well as pay my fines." 1 definitely seems fine. 2 I have a feeling is fine and is better than the "paying" alternative. @SConroy A pattern I've noticed is that these constructions sound odd with a third person singular subject. If you look at all the sentences given as incorrect examples in this thread, they are of this kind, "She manages the budget", "Running is healthy", "He broke the window", "She draws"

Comment: @zebrafish. Yes, agree -- that's what I thought too, but still  can't work out why. Also your sentence 1 sounds fine, but 'she vacuums the floor as well as mops it' sounds strange.

Comment: @mahmudkoya Your question wasn't getting the attention I think it deserved, and I [posted a question on our EL&U "meta" site](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11750) to ask why this might be the case. A number of users commented that the question's *title* wasn't very interesting, so I've followed one suggestion and edited it to make it more explicit. If you disagree with my edit, you can "roll back" (reject) my edit.

Comment: @SConroy *She vacuums as well as mops (the floor).*

Comment: Still sounds slightly off in my ears, but that could be personal preference. It also makes a difference exactly where in the sentence it occurs. You can't say (well you can, but it souns weird) As well as mops she vacuums; in that case the 'correct' version must be: As well as mopping she vacuums. After reading all the comments and answers, it seems to me to be on some scale of being a preposition like 'besides' and a conjunction like 'and' depending on the context of usage.

Comment: The examples in that first excerpt were horrible.  I wouldn't trust a reference that promotes such poor writing.

Answer (score 12):

No, the Merriam-Webster example is not wrong.

As far as Fowler, because he is a prescriptivist, I'm not sure it makes sense to call him 'wrong'. So he's advocating a ban on gerund-participials after *as well as*. Well, all I can say is that such a blanket ban would go against very solidly established usage, and that there is nothing intrinsically ungrammatical about the usage he wishes to ban. *Style*, however, is a different matter. I do agree that his gerund-free rewritings of the sample sentences do sound better than the originals, to my ear at least. But the originals are all perfectly acceptable English.

**The three functions of *as well as***

The point is that *as well as* has **three** uses, of which one is not relevant to your question, while the other two are.

The one that's **not relevant** to you is its **literal** meaning, which is used in comparisons of equality (*He played **as well as** he'd ever done*).

Now onto the two relevant meanings, both of which we may call **idiomatic**.

***As well as* functioning as a coordinator**

In its first relevant meaning, *as well as* is reanalyzed as a **coordinator** that roughly means *and*. One slight difference when using *as well as* this way is that, unlike with *and*, the second coordinate gets **backgrounded**. This *as well as* has most of the properties typical of coordinators. Just as with *and*, *or*, etc., the coordinates joined by *as well as* normally have to be syntactically alike (i.e if one is a noun phrase (NP), the other one must be as well; if one is a verb phrase (VP), the other one must be as well; etc.). And just like with *and*, if it's a coordination of NPs which serves as the subject of a clause, then the corresponding verb has to have plural agreement. An example of this is the *were* here: *[Abstraction] [as well as impressionism] **were** Russian inventions*.

This 'coordinator' meaning is the one used in the Merriam-Webster example. That example is a coordination of VPs. Note that *as well as* could be replaced by *and* without losing grammaticality, and with a minimal change in meaning, if any:

[We offer electronic toys] **as well as** [rent out video games].
[We offer electronic toys] **and** [rent out video games].

***As well as* functioning to introduce a subordinate element**

In its second relevant meaning, *as well as* functions differently. In this case, it introduces an element that is **subordinate** rather than **coordinate**. Therefore the elements that this *as well as* joins need not be syntactically alike, which is one of the reasons why we wouldn't be able to substitute *and* for *as well as* in such cases. This is the use of *as well as* seen in examples such as *Smoking is dangerous, as well as making you smell bad*.

**Analysis from CGEL**

For more details, here is [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) (pp. 1316-1317):

> The literal use of *as well as* is seen in comparisons of equality like *He played **as well as he'd ever done.*** Here *well* is an adverb heading the underlined [boldfaced] phrase, an adjunct of manner. There is also an idiomatic use meaning approximately "and, in addition to", illustrated in:
>
> [70]  i  a.  *She [means what she says] [**as well as** says what she means].*
>                b.  *[Abstraction] [**as well as** impressionism] were Russian inventions.*
>  
>                c.  *[Both increasing ewe liveweight,] [**as well as** liveweightat mating,] influence
>  
>                       ovulation rate and lambing performance.*
>  
>            ii  a.  *[Beauty] [**as well as** love] is redemptive.*
>  
>                b.  *He will have, [**as well as** the TV stations,] [a book publishing empire].*
>  
>                c.  *I met her father, [whom] she had invited along [**as well as** her college friends].*
>  
>                d.  *She [has experience in management], [**as well as** being an actor of talent].*
>
> In [i] *as well as* behaves like the coordinator *and*. In [ia] it links two finite VPs (verb phrases), a property characteristic of coordinators: cf. property (c) of §2.1. Note in this connection that while *She plays **the piano** as well as **the violin*** (with paired NPs) is ambiguous between a literal meaning ("as proficiently") and the idiomatic one ("and"), *She **plays the piano** as well as **sings lieder*** (with paired finite VPs) has only the idiomatic meaning. In [ib] the form *were* indicates that the subject NP is plural, just like *abstraction and impressionism*. And in [ic] we have not only such plural agreement, but also a correlative pairing of *both* with *as well as* instead of the usual *and*.
>
> In [70ii], by contrast, *as well as* behaves markedly differently from a coordinator. In [iia] the 3rd person singular verb-form *is* indicates that this time the subject is singular: *is* agrees with *beauty*, so that *as well as love* is treated syntactically as an adjunct, not a coordinate. In [iib] *as well as the TV stations* precedes *a book publishing empire*, making it clearly an adjunct. *And* could not appear in the position *as well as* has here: cf. property (d) of §2.1. In [iic] relativisation has applied to just one of the bracketed constituents, contrary to coordinator property (e). And in [iid] the bracketed constituents are syntactically unlike, the first being a finite VP, the second a gerund-participial, contrary to coordinator property (b). Note that order reversal is possible in [iid] (*As well as being an actor of talent, she has experience of management*), but not in [ia] (**As well as says what she means, she means what she says*).
>
> We must conclude that idiomatic *as well as* can be construed syntactically in two  ways, introducing an element that is either coordinate (as in [70i]) or subordinate (as in [ii]). In the former case, we take it to have been reanalysed as a compound coordinator. In the latter case there has been no such syntactic reanalysis, and here *as well as* does not form a constituent. This is evident from the fact that *as well* can occur on its own: compare *Beauty is redemptive and love is as well* In [iia], then, the second *as* is a preposition taking the NP *love* as its complement, and the whole PP *as love* is an indirect complement in the AdvP *as well as love*. Similarly for the other examples in [ii].
>
> As a coordinator, *as well as* is restricted to subclausal coordination: *She plays the piano as well as she sings lieder*, for example, has only the literal comparative interpretation. Even as a coordination, '*X as well as Y*' differs from '*X and Y*' in that the second term is backgrounded: *Y* often expresses information that is discourse-old, i.e. familiar from the prior discourse.

Comment: +1 for everyone being somewhat right as well as for the nice CGEL explanation.

Comment: Is CGEL saying that in 70iid the gerund-participial is correct, i.e. *She [has experience in management], [as well as being an actor of talent]*? It would certainly sound strange to say *She [has experience in management], [as well as is an actor of talent]*. Yet isn't the latter construction identical to *[We offer electronic toys] as well as [rent out video games]*?

Comment: Interestingly related: [Is there a grammatical mistake in this sentence:- The owner as well as his servants is honest](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/443211), in which you add "I should say that I have some misgivings about CGEL's argument for the claim that *as well as* is not a constituent in [70] ii".

Answer (score 3):

If this is a rule, it is one of fairly recent vintage. Looking in Google books, I find in [Exposition of the Grammatical Structure of the English Language](https://books.google.com/books?id=CHsSAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA386&dq=%22as+well+as%22+grammar&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwia7sL_xsfdAhUKMd8KHW40CYgQ6AEIPTAD#v=onepage&q=%22as%20well%20as%22%20grammar&f=false), by John Mulligan (New York, 1857) the quote:

> But when we say *This musician sings as well as plays*, the meaning is altogether different,

where here the book is contrasting this with the sentence *This musician sings as well as he plays.*

I don't know whether the usage has changed and we now prefer the gerund after *as well as*, whether more recent grammarians are suffering an attack of unfounded prescriptionism, or whether this detail of grammar varies between dialects (my guess). However, if this usage was acceptable to some grammarians in the 19th century, it should not be surprising that some people still use it in the 21st.

I would be very reluctant to call it outright ungrammatical.

Let me comment that, if the *as well as* clause comes first, you must use the gerund.  The first of the following sentences is ungrammatical:

> *As well as plays, the musician sings.
>   As well as playing, the musician sings.

If the prohibition against finite verbs after *as well as* is unfounded prescriptionism, this is probably where it comes from. Some grammarian decided that if a clause is ungrammatical before the verb, it should also be ungrammatical after it. This isn't the way English works—for example, whether you use *except* or *except for* can depend on the placement of the clause.

Comment: Good find. The quoted example seems right to me in the 21st century, yet the MW example sounds wrong to me. I wonder whether the *-ing* "practice" (in lieu of calling it a rule) has since evolved as a way of eliminating ambiguity *when the second verb has an object*? E.g. does "this musician sings as well as plays Bach" mean they both sing Bach and play Bach, or they play Bach and they also sing? A comma after "sing" directs us to the second meaning, but in spoken English commas can be harder to detect. Just a thought. Fascinating question!

Comment: How would Mulligan have judged "the musician sang as well as played"?

Comment: @Ami: since that's just putting his sentence into the past, I assume he would have thought it was perfectly fine. But I can't really tell.

Comment: I'm trying to get a feel for whether the phrase can take any tense, or needs something close to an infinite.

Comment: I think the two tenses have to be the same. *She sings beautifully, as well as composed three synphonies* sounds wrong ... you would need to use *as well as having composed.* And finite tenses sound best if the clauses are only a few words long ... for long clauses, these constructions sound much better if you use the gerund.

Answer (score 2):

I am grateful to all, especially, those who have posted their answers, expressed their views through comments and edited my question to make it more attractive and catchy. Still I am nowhere near a final conclusion as to what verb form should I use after *as well as*.

However, after reading the following excerpt from “*A Grammar of Contemporary English by Quirk et al*”, I assume I had better take a moderate stand – neither to be very strict in using only the **–ing** form as advised by *Michael Swan* or *The Free Dictionary* nor to consider *as well as* always a conjunction and use a finite verb after it as stated by *Fowler*. As per the following excerpt, *as well as* can function in sentences as a conjunction or preposition both without any change of meaning. Then, how can we blame the Merriam-Webster Dictionary for their example sentence!

> “There are several quasi-coordinators which behave sometimes like
>   coordinators and at other times (without any change of meaning) like
>   subordinators or prepositions. The most prominent of them are clearly
>   related to comparative forms: 
>   *as well as, as much as, rather than, more than*.  In the following examples, they do not introduce noun phrases or clauses, and therefore
>   resemble coordinators:
>
> *He publishes as well as prints his own books.*
>
> In other sentences, however, they clearly have a prepositional or
>   subordinating role:
>
> *As well as printing the books, he publishes them.”*

Comment: To me, in the phrase "as well as", the first 'as' feels like a coordinator, and the second feels like a preposition, but I don't see any subordination happening since it never introduces a clause (there's no subject).

Answer (score 1):

The question is ambiguous, it sounds as if you are actually looking for the tense of the verb rather than the verb itself. It would help us if you stated the specific use case. In the generic sense, the tense breaks down according to choice of usage, as noted by @Nigel J:

1) "As well as" used as a conjunction: Present continuous

2) "As well as" used for comparison: Present perfect

Comment: Where is the ambiguity? In the light of the  cited three examples, my question is whether we should use an -ing form or a finite verb after *as well as*.

Comment: Present continuous (be + V+ ing) : "She is dancing as well as singing" is this what you mean? If so, would "She danced as well as sung." be incorrect? What has the present perfect got to do with the question?

Comment: Wouldn't a coordinating conjunction be followed by any tense (although a repetition of the preceding tense would be preferred)?  Wouldn't a comparison (of verbs) do the same?  Does an infinite form (present or participle) lead us to assume a repetition of tense?

Answer (score -1):

***TL;DR***: You ask "What is the correct usage when we have to use a verb after as well as?" The simple answer, as your cited references already suggest, is to use the "-ing" form of the verb. I'll give further evidence to support this, but first I'll show that Merriam-Webster has probably got it wrong.

---

### 1. The MW example is incorrect

It's instructive to look at Merriam-Webster Dictionary's [example sentence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20well%20as) in greater detail:

> **as well as** (conjunction)
>   Definition of *As Well As* (Entry 1 of 2)
>   : and in addition : AND
>   - brave *as well as* loyal
>
> **as well as** (preposition)
>   Definition of *As Well As* (Entry 2 of 2)
>   : in addition to : BESIDES
>   - the coach, *as well as* the team, is ready
>
> **Examples of *As Well As* in a Sentence**
>   (Preposition)
>   - we offer electronic toys *as well as* rent out video games

Clearly the expression "as well as" is **not** a preposition in this sentence; it functions as a *coordinating conjunction*. MW is generally a reliable dictionary, but this would seem to be a rather glaring error. As a conjunction, "as well as" should take the "-ing" form of the verb in the second clause, so MW has simply compounded their error by using an incorrect example for their incorrect part of speech.

### 2. The correct usage

Grammarist's [explanation of conjunctions](http://grammarist.com/grammar/conjunctions/) puts "as well as" in two categories: (a) coordinating conjunctions, and (b) copulative conjunctions (also known as additive conjunctions), which are a specific type of coordinating conjunction.

Grammar hounds may find additional enlightenment in McCawley's *The Syntactic Phenomena of English*, a relevant extract of which is [available online](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC&pg=PA299&lpg=PA299&dq=%22as+well+as%22+Syntactic+Phenomena&source=bl&ots=uOgA6PdyRj&sig=qA9mN2l1Z84tfZs9O9OxxMfSaYA&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22as%20well%20as%22%20Syntactic%20Phenomena&f=false). McCawley notes that

> "inflections that are imposed on the whole putative coordinate
>   structure are realized on just the first conjunct, with the second
>   conjunct taking an *-ing* form irrespective of what inflection the
>   first conjunct has."

Finally, a simpler prescription is provided [here](http://site.uit.no/english/grammar/aswellas/), in which it's stated:

> VERBS AFTER *AS WELL AS* COME IN *–ING* FORM
>   When we put a verb after *as well as*, we use the *-ing* form of the verb. (This might sound really strange to a non-native speaker, but the grammar books agree on this.)
>
> *Running is healthy as well as **making** you feel good.
>
>   He broke the window, as well as **destroying** the wall.
>
>   She draws as well as **designing** clothes.*

Interestingly, the above source provides an additional perspective on the use of "as well as" *as a conjunction* that I hadn't previously considered, though it makes intuitive sense:

> *As well as* cannot be used to mean *and*. The expression *X as well as Y* means *not only Y but also X* (note that X and Y are reversed).
>   While *and* simply conjoins two (or more) expressions, *as well as*
>   places unequal emphasis on the two expressions — the expression
>   preceding *as well as* carries a stronger emphasis than the expression
>   following it.

Comment: Just a comment. The more I learn about this sort of stuff the more I think writers unconsciously selectively pick evidence supporting their point. Eg.,  "VERBS AFTER AS WELL AS COME IN –ING FORM", you'll notice that all three examples have a third person singular subject, and so the sentences sound unnatural and we then accept that the rule is sound and doing otherwise is clearly wrong. But if we were to take "I draw as well as design clothes", it no longer sounds as unnatural. A fair examination of the rule should not be so selective in its examples given, it seems tendentious, not neutral.

Comment: The Free Dictionary "Be Careful" note does the same thing, the subject is the third person singular, "Don't say, for example, 'She manages the budget as well as she orders the equipment'." If we try it with "I manage the budget as well as order the equipment" it doesn't sound as unnatural, but I don't know. I like you answer, I'm just not sure if this is an absolute universal rule or whether it's more nuanced than these explanations. Edit: also, very interesting about the preposition/conjunction discrepancy as given at Merriam-Webster.

Comment: @Zebrafish You might be right about subconscious bias, but it seems you've not understood the correctness of the grammar. "I draw as well as design clothes" means *something very different* from "I draw as well as designing clothes".

Comment: To be honest with you, both of them aren't exactly clear to me in meaning. But if the first one is acceptable (I'm not saying it is or isn't), then the rule is wrong as a universal prescription (which it seems to be) without further qualification. "I draw as well as designing clothes" actually sounds rather odd to me. Though "As well as designing clothes, I draw" sounds OK. This might be a personal quirk of mine. Maybe it's also a confusing example sentence, maybe the budget one is better to analyse.

Comment: I'm downvoting you, not because your answer is wrong (I don't know myself), but because your logic is just completely incorrect here. The fact that Merriam-Webster got the part of speech wrong has no bearing on whether they got the verb tense wrong. And further, I don't trust one of your sources: *Running is healthy as well as making you feel good* is terrible grammar (although changing the tense of *making* wouldn't improve it).

Comment: @PeterShor I appreciate you explaining. However: (1) I've merely drawn attention to a conjunction of MW errors; I'm not sure where the logical fallacy is there. Their example *is* poor English, and *sounds* like poor English. (2) I'm not sure where the "terrible grammar" is: MW defines "good" as an adverb = "well".

Comment: I'm pretty sure Peter Shor's comment about terrible grammar isn't about using "good" as an adverb, but the use of "making" after "as well as". I can't say it's bad grammar, because I can only subjectively say it sounds strange to my ear. Since none of us seem to be able to put a finger on what is the exact rule being violated here, we're at an impasse in objectively saying it's poor English. In my opinion, the M-W example sentence about renting out video games sounds better than the running example. But can't explain why, and am quite confused about this whole topic.

Comment: About the terrible grammar comment — I think what bothers me about the example is that *as well as* is connecting two phrases that are different parts of speech. I don't like *she is intelligent as well as a great dancer*, either. You can find sentences like this on the web, but not very many of them. I think it really should read something like *It makes you healthier, as well as making you feel good.*

Comment: Whatever is wrong with: "She draws as well as designs clothes"? In speech, that would be fine, as far as I'm concerned. It could be used for emphasis amid a longer discussions.  And "designing" there would be even more awkward. I would not use "as well as" as a coordinating conjunction there in writing in sentences such as that one e-v-e-r. :)

Comment: @Lambie What's wrong with it is that the meaning isn't clear. Does "She draws as well as designs clothes" mean "She draws clothes and she designs clothes", or "She designs clothes, and she draws [other things]"? The alternative construction, "She draws as well as designing clothes", can *only* mean the second option. But perhaps this usage is regionally variable, and almost certainly is also reflective of the level of experience in English.

Comment: @Chappo She draws as well as she designs clothes. That is your second meaning: with repetition of the pronoun.

Comment: @Lambie Do you see how ambiguous it becomes? So do you now mean that her ability to draw is equal to her ability to design clothes? Every time you try to avoid using the "-ing" construction, you introduce ambiguity and confusion. Why is it so hard to accept the *standard* construction?

Comment: @Chappo: Of course. She draws clothes as well as she designs them. [that is the comparative]. Without no repetition of the pronoun,it's conjunctional (my coinage). I play these things by ear, not by books. And that is what my interiorized grammar "wisdom" tells me.....you don't  have to agree. :) Also, this is spoken, not written. No one around here seems to pay that much heed.

Answer (score -5):

That aside, there is no contradiction and the Question is in no way ambiguous. “… we offer toys *as well as* rent out video games…” is simply wrong, which shows why and how your sources are right.

Precisely as specified, “… we offer toys as well as *renting* out video games…” is the correct form.

Please remember always that posting pictures instead of text is far from helpful.

Comment: "It both helps as well as hurts its members" is wrong according to this rule?

Comment: @Zebrafish Hmm, you've got me there! I've just posted an answer about using the *-ing* construction, but your example sounds right too. I think the use of "both" makes "as well as" function as a *copulative (or additive) conjunction*, but I'm not expert enough in grammar to do other than speculate whether this particular subset is exempted from the *-ing* rule.

Comment: @Zebrafish Yes, it's wrong. The element after *as well as* should augment, not mitigate. You can't say *help as well as hurt*. In fact, there isn't anything that completes "helps as well as ____". Ngrams has 0 hits for this string.

Comment: @PhilSweet Not sure what you mean by "augment, not mitigate". As dictionaries point out, it functions in a similar way to also, don't know what that has to with augmenting or mitigating, whatever that means. I'm not surprised Ngrams doesn't turn up results for that particular string. It's a very specific string I made up. Ngrams doesn't give results for "he fed his hamster" and "he enjoys climbing" either. Very hardly a test of whether something is grammatical or acceptable. Also, "as well as hurts" does turn up in Ngrams, as do many present tense third person singular words after "as well as"

Comment: Many variations turn up in Ngrams, "as well as walks", "as well as jumps", "as well as goes", all the ones I tried turn up results. Though as I illustrated, Ngrams doesn't seem to be a good test of whether something is grammatical or acceptable. I'm just using Ngrams as an example, I didn't bring up Ngrams as a topic, but it is interesting to see their results.

Comment: Ngrams will find past tense too ("as well as helped", "as well as slept").  The graphs of all tenses vary, but many of the finite ones peak in the late 1800s.

Comment: Zebrafish, you might use "It both helps as well as hurting its members" but yes, "helps as well as hurts" is wrong…